# How to implement an interface for two classes with an iterator

Tags: java

I'm trying out Interfaces in java and I want to implement a common interface for a really simple stack, with `pop()` and `push()` methods and an iterator.

The problem is that I don't know how to specify the iterator in the interface. No matter which way I try, I get

```
Main.java:32: error: for-each not applicable to expression type
                for (Integer i : ss)
                                 ^
required: array or java.lang.Iterable
found:    Stack<Integer>
```

The code is as follows:

```
interface Stack<T> {

    boolean push(T t);

    boolean pop();
    
    //Iterator<T> iterator(); // How to indicate it needs, and will have, an iterator?
}
```

```
public class DynamicStack<T> implements Iterable<T>, Stack<T>
{
    // implementation-specific variables go here

    public DynamicStack() {
        //...
    }

    public boolean push(T t) {
        //...
    }

    public boolean pop() {
        //...
    }
    
    private class StackIterator implements Iterator<T> {
        DynamicStack<T> stk;
        //...
        
        // Iterator constructor
        private StackIterator(DynamicStack<T> stk)
        {
            //...
        }

        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            //...
        }

        public T next() throws NoSuchElementException
        {
            //...
        }

        public void remove() throws UnsupportedOperationException
        {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); // I chose not to implement this one
        }
    }

    // Iterator method
    public Iterator<T> iterator()
    {
        return new StackIterator(this);
    }
}
```

```
public class StaticStack<T> implements Iterable<T>, Stack<T>
{
    // implementation-specific variables go here

    public StaticStack()
    {
        //...
    }

    public boolean push(T t)
    {
        //...
    }

    public boolean pop()
    {
        //...
    }

    private class StackIterator implements Iterator<T>
    {
        StaticStack<T> stk;
        //...

        private StackIterator(StaticStack<T> stk)
        {
            //...
        }

        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            //...
        }

        public T next() throws NoSuchElementException
        {
            //...
        }

        public void remove() throws UnsupportedOperationException
        {
            //...
        }
    }

    // Iterator method
    public Iterator<T> iterator()
    {
        return new StackIterator(this);
    }
}
```

Main simply does this, after creating a few stacks of each type and adding a few elements:

```
public static void showStuff(Stack<Integer> ss)
{
    for (Integer i : ss)
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Could you show the whole main class code? It seems like you are defining ss variable of class Stack which doesn't implement iterable, hence it fails

Comment: @ruba Indeed, ss is of class Stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your test class, you are operating against `Stack` interface, so that is the one that needs to conform to `Iterable`. In this case it doesn't help if `StaticStack` or `DynamicStack` implement it if `Stack` does not.

To get Stack to be able to be used as Iterable just change your Stack to extend Iterable:

```
public interface Stack<T> extends Iterable<T> {    

    boolean push(T t);

    boolean pop();        
}
```

and

```
public class StaticStack<T> implements Stack<T>
```

and the code runs just fine:

```
public class Tester {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Stack<Integer> ss = new StaticStack<>();
    for (Integer i : ss)
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I guess the rationale is saying that Stack is a child of Iterable<T> and that all those who implement Stack's interface must implement the Iterable<T> methods and the push and pop ones?

Comment: @Lightsong if you feel this has solved your question, consider accepting the answer (the checkmark below the up/downvote buttons)

Comment: @Lightsong the latter is true, all who implement Stack must also implement Iterable methods, in addition to Stack methods. About being a child... well, it extends Iterable, inheriting its features and adding some of its own. One can think of it as parent-child relationship but I don't call them that myself.

Answer (score 1):

You need you class to implement `Iterable<T>`, which has the `iterator()` method, which returns `Iterator<T>`.

Comment: If I do an `implements Iterable<T>`   in the interface, it will complain about an `illegal start of type`. How could I do that exactly?

Comment: If you're putting the type on an interface, use `extends`. If putting it on a class, use `implements`.